# a AudioStreamer IOS seekToTime

Tags: ios

I am working with streaming audio file first time, my audio file is streaming and seekTOTime is also working i.e stream audio from new selected position of slider but after that my slider gets flicked and I am getting wrong current time or playing time.

```
- (IBAction)currentTimeSliderValueChanged:(id)sender
 {
    [streamer seekToTime:self.currentTimeSlider.value * duration];
 }
```

and I am updating my slider values

```
if (streamer.bitRate != 0.0)
{
    double duration = streamer.duration;
    double progress = streamer.progress;
    int minProgress =  (int)progress/60%60;
    int secProgress = (int)progress%60;
    double totalSec = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
    int minDur =  (int)totalSec/60%60;
    int secDur = (int)totalSec%60;
    if(duration > 0)
    {
        [self.elapsedTimeLabel setText:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",
          minProgress,secProgress]];
        [self.remainingTimeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d",minDur,secDur]];
        [self.currentTimeSlider setEnabled:YES];
        [self.currentTimeSlider setValue: progress/duration];
    }
 }
```

But I am getting wrong value for elapsedTimeLabel after seekToTime and when streaming ends i get error 
"AudioQueue changed state in unexpected way."
"Audio queue get current time failed. err: ˇ˛˚ä -66678"

Comment: did You set the slider value?

Comment: I am calling action - (IBAction)currentTimeSliderValueChanged:(id)sender on valueChanged control event of  slider. Slider is taking its value from this method

Comment: No no when you load your stream. did you set the slider max and minimum value?

Comment: Ohh I am setting it from Interface builder my Max value is 1 and min value is 0

Comment: Its giving me wrong time only after using the seekToTime. If I will not change position for slider then streaming  works like a charm.

Comment: what is the duration?

Comment: duration calculates the duration of available audio from the bitRate and fileLength.and returns the calculated duration in seconds.